# parallel programming for a function taking two arguments from a list of data frames using R

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, mapply

I have a function called DTW in similarity measure package. It takes two matrix or data frame as its arguments and returns the Dynamic time warping distance. Those data frames are the longitudes and latitudes of trajectory.
My program looks like this and all the data frames like df1, df2,df3 and so on are available:

```
distance <- function(arg1,arg2) {
  DTW(arg1, arg2)
}
for(i in 1:length(LIST)){
  for(j in 1:length(LIST)){
    a <- get(paste0("df",i))
    b <- get(paste0("df",j)) 
    ddist[i,j] <- distance(a,b)
    print(ddist)
  }
}
```

I am making a matrix ddist in which all the values are inserted returned by distance function. The program is working fine. I want to make it fast using parallel programming like parapply or parlapply function.

Comment: If you want to do this in parallel you need to redesign it according to good practice. Your use of get is a no-go and won't work well in parallel. These data.frames should be together in a list. When you have fixed that I'd encourage you to study the vignettes of the foreach package.

Comment: Ok Roland. I will study it. Thanks.

Comment: @Roland How about parLappy pr parApply for parallel programming ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method to give you an idea of how to make it parallel

```
  k<-length(LIST)
 ddist<-matrix(0,k,k) 
library("doParallel")
cl<-makeCluster(4,outfile='')
registerDoParallel(cl)
for(i in 1:k) {
  a <- get(paste0("df",i))
  ddist[i,]=foreach(j = 1:k , .combine='cbind' ,.export=paste0("df",1:k)) %dopar% {
    b <- get(paste0("df",j)) 
    distance(a,b)
  }
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Having said that , things to evaluate

1. if the distance function takes more than 2 seconds ,then only use
   parallel
2. df1 , df2 etc may not be a good idea , store each
   dataframe as df[[1]] , df[[2]]. Better than using the get function
3. if length(k) is very huge , then the amount of time taken for
   transferring the exported df1,df2 etc is quite a long time  , hence
   try to hit the sweet spot of performance with various iterations
4. You can see the option of data.table where there is inplace edit,
   use this instead of the ddist as it might be faster
5. If this code is called within a function , then you might also need to 
   export the function ddist , like `.export=c(ddist,paste0("df",1:k))`
6. Change the "4" in makeCluster to chose the cores you want, as a 
   thumbrule , keep it as `detectCores()-1`